Is there a bistable compliant bowl shaped object which can be folded in half as its second state?
I have this image of a elongated bowl made of a flexible material, where if you fold it in half lengthwise towards the convex side, the half being folded would invert, making it have the same concavity as the other half it is being folded towards.  The sides perpendicular to the fold would splay outwards away from the centre line when being folded.
Below is a hand drawn image of what I am talking about.

The image on the right is the elongated bowl (concave section facing left).  The image on the left is the folded bowl, with the bottom folded towards the top right.
I'm trying to alter the structure while keeping the general geometry, such that there would be another low energy state when folded in this way, but I'm having difficulty thinking how this can be done.  I'm thinking of using a wire mesh so that I can remove sections of the geometry that is increasing the potential energy.  I have no issue with having some holes in the bowl, but I would like the primary stable state to still have the general shape of a bowl.
Is there a way of looking at this problem which would help me find a solution?  Maybe there are tools out there that would help?

Wouldn't the same mechanism that allows folding in half work for folding in 4? Instead of subdividing it in 2, subdivide into 4 parts, two opposite quarters "reversible".

Search: "silicone tray round"

@SF., do you mean something like this:  quarter bowl fold.  I'm not sure how that would help.  Even so, I think I would prefer if the lower half was in one piece, even if it is only at the end edge.

@Abel, I was very excited that you were going to point at something that already did this.... until I did the search.  How is that at all useful?

I believe the search should be enough to answer your titular question. My answer would be: Yes.
